# Python appending class with constructor

Tags: python, list, class, constructor, append

I'm using python to define a class, then append an instance of it to a list.

```
class town:
    def __init__(name_, x_, y_, mayor_):
        name = name_
        main_x = x_
        main_y = y_
        mayor = mayor_
        desc = desc_

def add_town(name_, x_, y_, mayor_):
    towns.append(town(name_, x_, y_, mayor_))
    town_number += 1

def onCommand():
    add_town(args[1], loc_x, loc_y, sender.getName())

onCommand()
```

Unfortunately, I get this error when add_town is executed:

> Caused by: Traceback (most recent call last):   File "",
>   line 95, in onCommandTown   File "", line 74, in add_town
>   TypeError: **init**() takes exactly 4 arguments (5 given)

Note: this is a shorted version of the code I'm using to keep things simple. Rest assured that all variables are defined correctly.

EDIT: Also, towns is a list.

Does anyone know why this error is here? I've been puzzling over it for half an hour and nothings happening...

Comment: you are missing the `self` argument in `__init__`

Comment: http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/classes.html

Answer (score 3):

change your `__init__` from

```
def __init__(name_, x_, y_, mayor_):
```

to

```
def __init__(self, name_, x_, y_, mayor_):
```

Also, you might have to make the initialized parameters class variables.

```
def __init__(self, name_, x_, y_, mayor_):

    self.name = name_
    self.main_x = x_
    self.main_y = y_
    self.mayor = mayor_
    self.desc = desc_
```

and access it as `self.name`, etc within the class methods.

Read more on [this here](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#object.__init__)

Comment: Thanks very much all, that worked perfectly. Is there some way of defining a "self" namespace so that I don't have to constantly type self.x ?